# How to loop through a vector in TCL?

Tags: python, numpy, tcl

I am new to tcl, and I couldn't figure out how to translate this code from python to TCL

```
import numpy as np

g0 = 7.88e12
Eox = np.array([155473, 15573, 1553, 1557473, 5473, 473, 1573, 19553])
E1 = 0.55e6
m = 0.7
fot= 1

D = float(input("rad dose"))

Fy = np.array([(abs(Eox)/(abs(Eox)+E1))**m])
Not = np.array([g0*D*Fy*fot])
Not[Not>6.8e18] = 6.8e18
Nit = (1.7e4*D)+1e10
if Nit > 5e12:
    Nit = 5e12

print(Not)
print(Nit)
```

Comment: Please post the TCL that you have written so far. I'll help you but I won't write the whole thing for you...

Comment: @Z4-tier its very bad. If I knew that this would have helped I would have posted it ! !( 
    set g 7.88e12
    set m 0.7
    set E1 0.55e6
    set  Eox {1e5 1e5 1e5 1e5 1e5 1e5 1e5 1e5}
    set Fy [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
    for {set i 0} { $i < 8 } { incr i }  {
 set $Fy($i) "[expr (abs( [lindex $Eox $i])/(abs( [lindex $Eox $i])+$E1))**$m]"
     }
)!

Answer (score 2):

Tcl doesn't process lists of values like *numpy* does (it's closer to standard Python) without an extension. I remember there being such a thing, but I've not used it and I can't remember the name right now. So I'll use standard Tcl. The closest analogy for a numpy array in standard Tcl is a list of values (though that's got more in common with a Python list or tuple than anything else).

I'll translate these four lines for you:

```py
Eox = np.array([155473, 15573, 1553, 1557473, 5473, 473, 1573, 19553])

Fy = np.array([(abs(Eox)/(abs(Eox)+E1))**m])
Not = np.array([g0*D*Fy*fot])
Not[Not>6.8e18] = 6.8e18
```

They become:

```
set Eox {155473 15573 1553 1557473 5473 473 1573 19553}

set Fy [lmap EoxVal $Eox {expr {
    (abs($EoxVal) / abs($EoxVal + $E1)) ** $m
}}]
set Not [lmap FyVal $Fy {expr {
    $g0 * $D * $FyVal * $fot
}}]
set Not [lmap NotVal $Not {expr {
    ($NotVal > 6.8e18) ? 6.8e18 : $NotVal
}}]
```

The use of `lmap` is doing the same thing that numpy's doing behind the scenes for you on those arrays. The last two commands can be combined though:

```
set Not [lmap FyVal $Fy {expr {
    min($g0 * $D * $FyVal * $fot, 6.8e18)
}}]
```

(Also, I've split each of the `lmap/expr` commands over multiple lines for increased clarity. You can write more compact code, but it's harder to read. Clear code is a *very* good plan in any code you intend to keep around for longer than 5 minutes.)

---

The other lines of code are pure basic stuff. `set`, `puts`, `gets` and `expr` will do what you need. And the suspiciously obvious `if`.

Comment: I use numpy at work, and I don't like it because it's extremely difficult to make code that is not very cryptic using it. It easily becomes a matter of guessing until the magic happens. I hate that.

Comment: `lmap` is just a collecting `foreach`

Comment: Yes I know , I don’t always think about using it... and your answer shows a great example of its use . Thanks

Comment: Re lists and tuples, Tcl lists have value semantics like Python tuples, but operations that simulate much of what Python lists do. That's based on copy-on-write low-level semantics, which in turn depends on the threading model to be at all performant; this is an area where Tcl can use a solution that Python cannot. Subtle stuff.